# Using the method of isoclines with logistic equation to create direction field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

I am a little unsure on how to use the method of isoclines to model $\frac{dp}{dt} = 3p-2p^2$. As far as I know I need to set $3p-2p^2 = c$ where $c$ is the slope of the field on that line. When I set any arbitrary c and complete the square I get a parabola. But when I check the answer in the back of the book, I am completely wrong. [Their solution looks like this.](http://prntscr.com/8aqpqv). Any suggestions on how they got their solution like this?

Comment: When you set an arbitrary $c$, you have to solve for $p$ in $3p-2p^2 = c$ and plot lines $p = {\rm const}$ with obtained values. And then you know that at this lines you have slope equal to $c$. That's what isoclines method is all about (almost).